# how to sum 2 input values ​but in one form with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to sum 2 input values ​​but in one form with JavaScript, like this image:

[image: This]

then the output will be 350. is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Use `value.split('+')` to get the two parts into an array. Convert each array element to a number, and add them.

Comment: Be more specific about the expected behavior. Do you want the sum "350" to replace the values in the input field, or output it somewhere else? And do you want the sum to be calculated as the user types, when a button is pressed, or when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

```
const sum = value
  .split('+')
  .map(value => Number(value))
  .reduce((agg, val) => agg + val, 0);
```

Where `value` is the value from your form. This will also work for longer chains and with or without spaces, like `1 + 2+3`.